# Emberjs dynamic segment route only works once

Tags: javascript, ember.js, controller, routes

The emberjs docs say the following.

> Note: A route with a dynamic segment will only have its model hook called when it is entered via the URL. If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the link-to Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and the hook is not executed. Routes without dynamic segments will always execute the model hook.

How do I get the dynamic segment routes setupController code to execute every time.  This seems to be an on going issue; see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/2267).

The first time my code works.  I press a button and everything executes as expected.  But if I press the back button then press my application's button, there is information missing.  Then if I refresh the page, everything is working again.

I populated an array to be displayed along side my model info.  But when I navigate to that page via link, or press the back button, the array of information seems to be empty.  I added some `console.logs` and it looks my code is getting executed but when it comes to the template displaying the contents of the array, it is empty.

The solutions that have been raised talk about afterModel functions however, the logic that I need to execute (more then the first time it is loaded) is in a setupController function.  Other solutions I saw involve complex helpers that seem to be over kill for just executing code every time a user hits a specific route.

So basically, how do you force dynamic segment routes to act like it was entered through the url bar?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i'm perfectly happy to take a look at this, but would you mind please posting some code that demonstrates your issue (jsbin prefererably)? makes it easier to comment.

Comment: going down the tree model hooks and setupController hooks are executed, going up the tree model and setupController hooks aren't reexecuted.  If your route is already in the page, it won't fire again.  You might want to look into willTransition and didTransition as a mechanism for updating some property when you leave a child route, or by watching the currentPath in the application controller.  A more specific answer can't be provided without a more concrete example.

Comment: Ok this is weird.  When I do an `ember build --environment=production ...` then everything works as expected.  But when I access the pages in question with out it being built, I can only get the info on the page the first time I go to the page.
@Kingpin2k and @ChristopherMilne my code is a bit complex and I have never used jsbin, so it may take me some time to show an example that denotes my issue.

Comment: emberjs.jsbin.com has a prebuilt ember template.